# Reprogramming VID/PID of a USB device

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I have two USB thumb drives that I can boot from. The problem is that they are from the same vendor so they both appear with the same name in the boot list and I don't know which one to choose (their order changes bases on the USB port they are plugged into). The thing is, I must have both plugged in all the time.

Is there a way to change the VID/PID of the USB device so that the BIOS will show them as two different devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vendor ID and Product ID are stored in the USB device itself, so to change them you would have to have know what chips are on the device and know how to reprogram them.  The reprogramming (if possible) would probably require extra hardware which is likely to be more expensive than the alternative of just buying another thumb drive.

What file system are you using (e.g. NTFS, ext3)?  Ideally, your BIOS would be able to read the name of the volume and display that to you, the same way Windows and Linux do when you plug in a thumb drive.